# Angular: get list of all validators from a FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I might be wrong here, but after a bit of research it seems impossible to extract the list of validators from a FormControl

```
const ctrl = new FormControl(null,[Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]});
```

I would like a list with these validators, so I can do something like this (in theory)

```
const validators = ctrl.getValidators();
ctrl.setValidators( [...validators, myOwnValidator]);
```

Ideally I would like to append a validator, but as far as I know that is not possible.

I found two suggestions on the internet to access the validators on a FormControl:

1)

```
const validator = ctrl.validator('' as any as AbstractControl);
// -> {required: true}
```

2. const validator = ctrl.validator({} as AbstractControl);
   // -> {required: true}

Both options do exactly the same thing, they return an object with just one key `required` and a value `true`. Not very useful because I don't see anything about the other validator and I need the validator classes (because I need to set the validators again).

What I have found so far is not very useful, so I was wondering if I missed something. So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to put all validators in one variable ?

Comment: you mean that `validators` const? Because I need to add another validator, so I need all the existing ones.

Comment: Could you tell me what's the goal ? What you want to do on your formControl now or in the future ?

Comment: which version of angular do you use?

Comment: I'm using angular 12.1.0

Comment: I have upodated my ansert

Comment: I get the feeling, that it is all intentionally done this way. And I must admit, now that I think again about the problems I have to fix, that there are other ways too to do what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for **Angular 12.2.0**

```
this.form.controls["firstName"].addValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```

[image]

Solution for **angular 11 and below**

you can define validators for specific control into variable and then reuse it

```
public ctrlDefaultValidators = [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required];
public ctrl = new FormControl(null, ctrlDefaultValidators});

ctrl.setValidators( [...ctrlDefaultValidators , myOwnValidator]);
```

ps: dont forget to call `updateValueAndValidity`

Comment: Do you have a link to the angular documentation, because I can't find anything about `addValidators`

Comment: sorry, it is not present in your version, it is added in v12.2.0. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1220-rc0-2021-07-28

Comment: you can try it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chap12-l11

Comment: @shutsman Please create an answer for all the future poor lost souls working on Angular versions older than 12.2